# Substring-after value validate wtith another tag value format

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

My XML is below

```
<root>
<art-id p-type="main">XX.1108/ABCDE-01-2000-2000</art-id>
    <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000001" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 1</label>
            <caption>
                <p>xxxx</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
        <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000002" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 2</label>
            <caption>
                <p>YYYY</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
        <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000003" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 3</label>
            <caption>
                <p>ZZZZ</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
</root>
```

My XSL is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
                extension-element-prefixes="saxon" version='2.0'>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="FG-F-001">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*:f">
            <xsl:variable name="xxx" select="substring-after(//*:article-id[@pub-id-type='doi'],'/')"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(matches(@id,'^F_') and matches(.,'{$xxx}'))">
                <message name="{name()}">“f” tag attribute “id” value must be in the format "F_[main suffix][nnn]".
                </message>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to validate "f" tag "id" attribute value against "art-id". The value in "f" tag should be in format "F_[main tag suffix after / symbol value ][nnn]" (ie: F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000001).

Comment: With XPath/XSLT 2.0 you have regular expression support with e.g. `matches` so it seems you can build a regular expression from your `art-id` value and the requirements to have three digits (if I interpret `[nnn]` correctly) and simply use that function.

Comment: "art-id" tag value after "/" should match exactly in "f" tag also the format should be validated. "[nnn]" represents 3 digit random number.

Comment: Read up on `fn:matches` and the regular expression format it supports and construct a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow along the lines of

```
  <xsl:template match="f[not(matches(@id, '^F_' || ../art-id/substring-after(., '/') || '[0-9]{3}$'))]">
    <error f="{label}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

XPath 3.1 slipped in so if you are stuck with XPath 2.0 use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="f[not(matches(@id, concat('^F_', ../art-id/substring-after(., '/'), '[0-9]{3}$')))]">
    <error f="{label}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen i have assigned a variable for the pattern and it produced the expected result:
```<xsl:template name="FG-F-001">
<xsl:for-each select="descendant::node()[not(self::f)]">
<xsl:variable name="test1">
<xsl:text>^(F[_]</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//*:article-id[@pub-id-type='doi'],'/')"/><xsl:text>[0-9]{1,})$</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="matches(@id,$test1)">
<message name="{name()}">“f” tag attribute “id” value must be in the format "F_[main suffix][nnn]".</message>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a single XPath 2.0 expression that returns all invalid values**:

```
 for $id in concat('F_', substring-after(/*/art-id, '/'))
   return
     /*/f/@id[not(starts-with(., $id))
            or
              (for $suf in substring-after(., $id)
                 return not('000' le $suf and '999' ge $suf))
              ]/string()
```

**XSLT 2.0  - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "for $id in concat('F_', substring-after(/*/art-id, '/'))
       return
         /*/f/@id[not(starts-with(., $id))
                or
                  (for $suf in substring-after(., $id)
                     return not('000' le $suf and '999' ge $suf))
                  ]/string()
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (just added two invalid values):

```
<root>
<art-id p-type="main">XX.1108/ABCDE-01-2000-2000</art-id>
    <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000001" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 1</label>
            <caption>
                <p>xxxx</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
        <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000002" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 2</label>
            <caption>
                <p>YYYY</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
        <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2000003" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 3</label>
            <caption>
                <p>ZZZZ</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
        <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2010004" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 3</label>
            <caption>
                <p>ZZZZ</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
        <f id="F_ABCDE-01-2000-2010005" orientation="portrait">
            <label>F 3</label>
            <caption>
                <p>ZZZZ</p>
            </caption>
        </f>
</root>
```

**it outputs all the invalid values**:

```
F_ABCDE-01-2000-2010004    F_ABCDE-01-2000-2010005
```

Comment: Hi @Dimitre Novatchev, Thanks for your response, i have assigned a variable for the pattern and it produced the expected result: 
`<xsl:template name="FG-F-001">
<xsl:for-each select="descendant::node()[not(self::f)]">
<xsl:variable name="test1">
<xsl:text>^(F[_]</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//*:article-id[@pub-id-type='doi'],'/')"/><xsl:text>[0-9]{1,})$</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="matches(@id,$test1)">
<message name="{name()}">“f” tag attribute “id” value must be in the format "F_[main suffix][nnn]".</message>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> </xsl:template>`